# Why do I still I get money from my drivers after I've fired them all?

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

I had 20 drivers maxed out, but I decided to start earning money on my own so I fired them all. Unfortunately I still get notifications (didn't find a job, levelled up, job income etc) from these drivers, yet my company is empty.

Loading previous saves and then firing them doesn't work. Verifying game cache does not help either. I've disabled all mods, sold all the garages and trucks, used `g_force_economy_reset 1`, but still no results.

Video showcasing the problem:

Comment: I have this bug in my current game as well. Annoying as hell.